# Reconciling Chrome Shortcuts in Parallels

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, tabs, shortcut

On OS X, a new Chrome tab can be opened by pressing <kbd>Cmd+T</kbd>, but on Windows you press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>. This works fine if you map <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Parallels, but becomes problematic when cycling between tabs.

In Windows <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> advances to the next tab, but in OS X <kbd>Cmd+Tab</kbd> switches between applications. As a result I am constantly context-switching for Chrome between OS X and Windows in Parallels. Furthermore, I have to move a finger to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to cycle between tabs on OS X.

Is there a recommended way to reconcile these differences so that I can preferably cycle between tabs with <kbd>Cmd+Tab</kbd> without ruining other key combinations?

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is to go into Parallels Preferences and add the key-binds I use:

- <kbd>Cmd-Shift-R</kbd> Full Refresh
- <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> Simple Refresh
- <kbd>Cmd-Shift-I</kbd> Open Dev Tools
- <kbd>Cmd-O</kbd> While Dev Tools are open, search for a file

Maybe others will have additional shortcuts that they use.